# C# how to use generic constraint with interface

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me what am i doing wrong with the following c# code?
I am basically trying to add the constraint to ICommandHandler.

```
public interface ICommand<T> where T : BaseDto{ }

public abstract class BaseCommand<T> : ICommand<T> where T : BaseDto { }

public class CreateAlertCommand : BaseCommand<AlertDto>{}   

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand{}
```

I am getting error when defining ICommandHandler. It says `'Using the generic type ICommand<T> requires 1 type argument'`

Comment: You don't have an `ICommand` type. You have an `ICommand<T>` type. If you want a non-generic `ICommand` type, you have to create one.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps me to understand.

Comment: Just a small and unrelated note, class name, "CreateAlertCommand" should be just "AlertCommand" as class name should be noun and not verbs.

Comment: @Yogee Classes can represent verbs in which case the naming is correct. This seems appropriate in this case as the `...Command` classes represent commands, which are necessarily verbs.

Comment: @dai , you are right. If "CreateAlert" is a command, the name is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
}
```

Should be:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand,TDto>
    where TCommand : ICommand<TDto>
    where TDto : BaseDto
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is awesome.